# Difficulties with implementation of stack

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, stack, function-definition

I am trying to get into structures, but i got stuck. Here I tried to implement the main functions of the stack:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define N 10

    struct docEdit 
{
    char text[20];
    int StrNum;
};


struct Stack {
    struct docEdit items[N];
    int top;
};
    
void pushstack(struct Stack* st, struct docEdit myEvent1) {
if (st->top == N - 1) {
    printf("Stack is full");
    return;
    }   
    
    st->items[st->top++] = myEvent1;
}

    void popstack(struct Stack* st) {
    if (st->top == -1) {
        printf("Stack is empty");
        return;
    }
        st->top--;
    }

    int emptystack(struct Stack* st) {
        return st->top = 0;
    }

    int sizestack(struct Stack* st) {
        return st->top;
    }

    (//function data type//) top(struct Stack* st) {
        return st->items[st->top];
    }



    int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    struct Stack st;
    st.top = -1;
    struct docEdit myEvent1 = {"string 1", 1};

    pushstack(&st, myEvent1);
    popstack(&st);

    return 0;
    }
```

There are two questions: why does it write that the st variable is not initialized and what data type should the top function have? I would also be very grateful if you point out my mistakes and inaccuracies.

Comment: @adislaus01231 "why does it write that the st variable is not initialized" - You wrote the code and are you asking us why you wrote it such a way?!

Comment: Stack contains `struct docEdit`s, so it should return a `struct docEdit`. Depending on how you plan on using the stack, there's a good case for returning `struct docEdit *`. Just remember to not pop it until after you're done with the reference.

Comment: You can write typdef before you create each structure ,using the typedef allows you to write docEdit/Stack instead of having to write struct docEdit/Stack all the time. It is not required, it is just a convenience. You don't need to use the typedef to get your code to work. You can continue writing struct docEdit & structStack everywhere instead, if you wish

Comment: Please indent your code properly. That's a good style, plus it makes it much easier for others to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function definitions contradict each other. For example the function `popstack`

```
void popstack(struct Stack* st) {
if (st->top == -1) {
    printf("Stack is empty");
    return;
}
    st->top--;
}
```

states that the stack is empty when st->top == -1. On the other hand the function `emptystack` (that maybe has a typo and uses the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` That is unclear whether the function cleans the stack or reports whether it is empty)

```
int emptystack(struct Stack* st) {
        return st->top = 0;
    }
```

states that the stack is empty when `st->top` is equal to 0.

Or the function `sizestack`

```
int sizestack(struct Stack* st) {
        return st->top;
    }
```

states that the size is equal to the value `st->top`. It is evident that the maximum size of the stack is equal to `N` due to the declaration

```
struct docEdit items[N];
```

However the function `pushstack`

```
void pushstack(struct Stack* st, struct docEdit myEvent1) {
if (st->top == N - 1) {
    printf("Stack is full");
    return;
    }   
    
    st->items[st->top++] = myEvent1;
}
```

states that the stack is full when `st->top` is equal to `N - 1`.

That is you should decide whether the initial value of the data member `top` must be equal either `-1` or `0` and adjust correspondingly all function definitions.

As for the function `top` then it should return a pointer to an element of the stack.

```
struct docEdit * top( struct Stack* st) {
        if ( st->top != 0 )
        return st->items + st->top - 1;
        else
        return NULL; 
    }
```

Using the returned pointer you can change values of the element on the top of the stack. In this function I suppose that when the stack is empty then `st->top` is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are two lines that cause the problem.

The first one is in the `main` function:

```
st.top = -1;
```

And the second in the `pushstack` function:

```
st->items[st->top++] = myEvent1;
```

What these two lines does is the same as:

```
st->items[-1] = myEvent1;
```

And `-1` is an invalid index for an arry.

The solution is simple: Use *pre* increment `++` instead:

```
st->items[++st->top] = myEvent1;
```

This will first increment `st->top` from `-1` to `0`, and use `0` as the index.